# Force logout in VBS Script

Tags: vbscript

I've been working on a script that is ran whenever a user logs in. It checks against a .csv file containing machine names and usernames. If the machine the user is logging into is in the .csv file and the user is not "assigned" it will log them out. This works great for some accounts but there are a few that have restrictions and can not "run/execute" command prompt due to policies.

I've been using

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd.exe /C timeout.exe /t 10 /nobreak && shutdown.exe /l", 0, False
```

Which works fine for the users without the restrictions in place. I was wondering if there is any way to force a logout without using cmd.exe in VBS? The only solution I have been able to think of is calling/running the script as a separate user that has the right permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleep for 10 seconds, then call `logoff.exe` (or `shutdown.exe /l` if you prefer that).

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 10000
oShell.Run "logoff.exe", 0, False
```

`cmd /c` in your script is only required because you're chaining two commands (`timeout.exe` and `shutdown.exe`) via `&&`, which is a CMD-builtin feature. But since you don't allow the user to interrupt the timeout anyway you can just as well call `Sleep`.

However, since you say that you want to control which computer a user can and cannot log into: you can specify a list of the allowed computers in a user's settings in Active Directory (*Account → Log On To...*). This might be a better approach than running a script checking a CSV at logon.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have to give it a go and see if shutdown.exe or logoff.exe are blocked on those accounts. The reason I have done it with a CSV file is because Admin staff (with no access to AD) will need to be able to change which users have access to the specific workstations while I'm off-site.

Are there any parameters to allow a simple MsgBox to open without stopping code execution?

Comment: @Orion The proper solution for handling workstation access would be delegation control of an OU with the respective users to the group of people who need to manage that. Or establish an automated task that updates user settings from a CSV.

Comment: If you want to display a message with a timeout you can use the [`Popup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/x83z1d9f%28v%3dvs.84%29) method.

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely better ways to do it but unfortunately with the way the organization I'm working in has it set up I have barely any control over AD itself which forces me to do little workarounds like this. Thank you for the pointers.